# bind vs apply: Is there a difference between these two?

Tags: javascript, bind, apply

Consider the following function:

```
function bind(fn, context) {
  return function() {
    return fn.apply(context, arguments);
  }
}
```

Is this function doing exactly the same thing as `Function.prototype.bind`?

I.e., given the function definition above, should the following two lines of code achieve exactly the same thing?

```
boundFunction = bind(someFunction, someContext);

// same same?

boundFunction = someFunction.bind(someContext);
```

If there are any subtle or not-so-subtle differences, what are they?

(I'm asking, becaue I saw the function defined above used in some JavaScript and am wondering why they did not simply use `Function.prototype.bind`.)

Comment: Your version ignores further arguments.

Comment: They may have been targetting older browsers.

Comment: Your two lines of code are identical, but this definition for the user-defined `bind()` does not allow bound arguments to precede passed-in arguments like the prototype `bind()` method.

Answer (score 0):

So, building on comments, this seems to be the answer:

In my example, the two lines ...

```
boundFunction = bind(someFunction, someContext);
boundFunction = someFunction.bind(someContext);
```

... are indeed achieving the same result.

However, the "bind" function defined in this way does not provide the possibility to bind further arguments, like `Function.prototype.bind` does, i.e. something like this:

```
function abc(a, b, c) {
  console.log('a: '+a, 'b: '+b, 'c: '+c);
}

// This function predefines the first argument for abc:
var bc = abc.bind(undefined, 'Ay!');
abc('Yo!', 'hello', 'world');
// a: Yo! b: hello c: world
bc('hello', 'world');
// a: Ay! b: hello c: world
```